# Android - using AudioManager to play/pause music?

Tags: java, android, audio, android-audiomanager

My question is how can I use the AudioManager class to 1) see if a music service is open, and 2) if it's paused, play it, if it's playing, pause it..?

So far all I've really done is initialize an instance of it:

```
AudioManager AM = (AudioManager) getSystemService(AUDIO_SERVICE); 
if (AM.isMusicActive()) {
    //how do I pause whatever music player is active?       
}
```

Similarly, if a music player is open and paused, how do I play it? I've looked into the MediaPlayer class but I'm not sure how to use it with AudioManager (or if I even want to). While I'm asking questions, is there manifest permissions I need to worry about?

Thanks guys!

Comment: tried this with no luck    final Intent playButtonIntent = new Intent(
     Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_BUTTON);
   playButtonIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_KEY_EVENT,
     KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MEDIA_PLAY);
   context.sendBroadcast(playButtonIntent);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 2) if it's paused, play it, if it's playing, pause it..?

There are no APIs to do this. You can request the audio focus if you need to *temporarily* take over audio playback (e.g., to play a ringtone associated with an alarm).

> Similarly, if a music player is open and paused, how do I play it?

You don't.

> I've looked into the MediaPlayer class but I'm not sure how to use it with AudioManager (or if I even want to).

`MediaPlayer` is for playing media in your own application.

Comment: You mean to say one cannot use AudioManager to play song in their app and have to use MediaPlayer right?

Comment: @berserk: `AudioManager` is not used for playing a song.

Comment: @CommonsWare - how do i access the media player (or current running instance of a media player) in the same if condition above, inside a service sir??

Answer (score 0):

Tasker does it. At least pausing playback. It doesn't look like it can start it again.